# HAProxy path_beg cannot redirect

Tags: networking, haproxy, nat

I want to redirect so that I can connect to /test, but it doesn't work. How can I modify the code to access /test?

```
global
    daemon

defaults
    mode               http

frontend  http-in
    bind *:80
    acl url path_beg -i /test
    acl chrome hdr_sub(User-Agent) Chrome
    acl safari  hdr_sub(User-Agent) Safari
    default_backend    backend_servers
    use_backend bk_url if url
    use_backend bk_chrome if chrome
    use_backend bk_safari if safari
backend backend_servers
    balance            roundrobin
    server             web 10.31.0.100:80 cookie w1 check
    server             web01 10.31.0.104:80 cookie w2 check
    server             ns 10.31.0.103:80 cookie w3 check
backend bk_url
    server             web   10.31.0.100:80
backend bk_chrome
    server             web01 10.31.0.104:80
backend bk_safari
    server             ns    10.31.0.103:80
```

How should I configure the acl and use_backend settings?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put default_backend as last in the list, like this:

```
use_backend bk_url if url
use_backend bk_chrome if chrome
use_backend bk_safari if safari
default_backend backend_servers
```

The documentation is not very explicit about it but my guess is that when haproxy encounters a default_backend rule, it will grab it and not look for any other use_backend rules down the line.

https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/onepage/#4-default_backend